# jHtmlArea adding unwanted BR tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jhtmlarea

Am using the `jHtmlArea` plugin on a project and it appears to be adding unwanted `BR` tags to the end of whatever the user inputs, but I can't see what in the plugin code is making this happen. Other people have asked elsewhere about it adding `P` tags or `DIV` tags but they weren't getting their questions answered. Of course I would like to find a way to keep the unwanted tags from ever being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the <br> was being added after a validation test when validating an empty field, so I looked to see if the input was dirtied by the unwanted 
 tag and reset it to empty.

```
if($("#post").val().trim() == "<br>") {
  $("#post").val("");
}
```

Its a dirty bug-fix, but it does exactly the job I need it to. Perhaps you can modify it for your purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the case with WYSIWYG Content editors. I took a quick look and didn't see anything in the jHtmlArea-0.7.5.js file that would be of use.

A quick fix would to be add the style `br {display:none;}` but thats not an optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, we actually need it removed so it's not even part of the database. The back end guy thinks he might have a back end solution to implement...

Comment: Ahh sorry, thought this was a pure front-end issue. Makes sense.

Comment: Okay, I am now learning that this is a Firefox thing. IE and Chrome are not adding a BR tag into the IFRAME.

Comment: Okay, new update in case it ever helps anybody: it appears now that the unwanted BR tag is coming from Firebug, not Firefox.

Comment: Even newer update: it might still actually be Firefox. This issue cropped up in Firefox 3.1.1 and appears to still not be corrected in version 19. http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/5293

Comment: You should post this as an answer and mark it accepted even if it's a FF version bug :} That way other people searching can find what the issue is.

Comment: The thing is that I don't have answer. I have tried every scripting trick I can think of to get the tag to go away but to no avail. The only thing I learned yesterday is that it seems to be a Firefox-only issue. Chrome and IE seemed to have similar problems in their earlier versions but seem to have gotten rid of those problems.

Comment: The reason this is important in my project is because we have to cap a length at how many characters can be input a TEXTAREA element (500 in this case) but we don't want users to get four less characters than they deserve (is that the right word here?) just because Firefox insists on including unwanted elements.

Comment: But maybe I can post the most that has been learned thus far as the "answer" even if it's not the "solution"?

Comment: Can you just bump the max char limit to 504 in that case? If it's not too big an issue for your data.

Comment: I am thinking too that that might be the solution here in order to pander to the Firefox bug. Hopefully the "higher ups" here don't mind a 4-character-allowable increase.

Comment: When you run into a wall like this, I'd suggest going to them after a a 30mins - 2 hours if you don't solve it. That way you won't waste time on an unachievable solution if the business requirements can easily change :} I've done this a lot.